# Does facebook sdk for iOS use encryption?

Tags: iphone, facebook, encryption

I don't know how to answer the question:

Export laws require that products containing encryption be properly authorized for export.
Failure to comply could result in severe penalties.
For further information, click here.
Is your product designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography?
Yes         No

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer, but the question is related to 'are you implementing/using encryption explicitly'. If you're only making use of https, then the answer to this question is no.